# Melt and pivot a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working with a publicly available election data set that I've imported into Pandas as a df:

```
    fips_code   county              total_2008  dem_2008    gop_2008     oth_2008   total_2012  dem_2012    gop_2012    oth_2012    total_2016  dem_2016    gop_2016    oth_2016
0   26041       Delta County        19064       9974        8763        327         18043       8330        9533        180         18467       6431        11112       924
1   48295       Lipscomb County     1256        155         1093        8           1168        119         1044        5           1322        135         1159        28
2   1127        Walker County       28652       7420        20722       510         28497       6551        21633       313         29243       4486        24208       549
```

I would like to get to something like this:

```
fips_code   county          total   dem     gop     oth year
26041       Delta County    19064   9974    8763    327 2008
48295       Lipscomb County 1256    155     1093    8   2008
1127        Walker County   28652   7420    20722   510 2008
```

I've searched around and found something similar, [Stack and Pivot Dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172581/stack-and-pivot-dataframe-in-python), but I can't figure out how to apply that to my question.

I managed to do a melt of the df:

```
In [86]:
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['fips_code', 'county'], value_name='num_votes')
df_melt.head()

Out [86]:
fips_code       county              variable    num_votes
0   26041       Delta County        total_2008  19064
1   48295       Lipscomb County     total_2008  1256
2   1127        Walker County       total_2008  28652
3   48389       Reeves County       total_2008  3077
4   56017       Hot Springs County  total_2008  2546
```

This is where I get stuck because I can't figure out if it's a multi-step process that starts with using the melt, or if there's a straightforward way to get there from the initial df I have. I'm not even sure what functions I should be using, but it looks like it involves pivot/stack/unstack? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wide to long question again .[wide_to_long](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['total','dem','gop','oth'],i=['fips_code','county'],j='Year',sep='_').reset_index()
Out[28]: 
   fips_code          county  Year  total   dem    gop  oth
0      26041     DeltaCounty  2008  19064  9974   8763  327
1      26041     DeltaCounty  2012  18043  8330   9533  180
2      26041     DeltaCounty  2016  18467  6431  11112  924
3      48295  LipscombCounty  2008   1256   155   1093    8
4      48295  LipscombCounty  2012   1168   119   1044    5
5      48295  LipscombCounty  2016   1322   135   1159   28
6       1127    WalkerCounty  2008  28652  7420  20722  510
7       1127    WalkerCounty  2012  28497  6551  21633  313
8       1127    WalkerCounty  2016  29243  4486  24208  549
```

Comment: Oh neat! I didn't realize you could give `.wide_to_long` a list of stubs. Nice answer :D

Answer (score 0):

One option to abstract the reshaping process is with
[pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index = ['fips_code', 'county'], 
    names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
    names_sep = '_')

   fips_code           county  year  total   dem    gop  oth
0      26041     Delta County  2008  19064  9974   8763  327
1      48295  Lipscomb County  2008   1256   155   1093    8
2       1127    Walker County  2008  28652  7420  20722  510
3      26041     Delta County  2012  18043  8330   9533  180
4      48295  Lipscomb County  2012   1168   119   1044    5
5       1127    Walker County  2012  28497  6551  21633  313
6      26041     Delta County  2016  18467  6431  11112  924
7      48295  Lipscomb County  2016   1322   135   1159   28
8       1127    Walker County  2016  29243  4486  24208  549
```

No need to explicitly name the prefixes; the `.value` identifies the prefixes, pulls them out, and sets them as headers, while the rest are transposed into the `year` column. The dtype of the year column can also be changed to numeric efficiently, via the `names_transform` parameter:

```py
df.pivot_longer(
    index = ['fips_code', 'county'], 
    names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
    names_transform = {'year' : int},
    names_sep = '_')
```